# DefaultPolicy is still being used when using AllowAnonymousFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on authorization in a .NET Core 3.1 API. In this project, I cannot use the `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes in the controllers directly. Instead, I created custom conventions that implement `IApplicationModelConvention`. These are added to the conventions inside the AddControllers() options:

```
services.AddControllers(o =>
            {
                 o.Conventions.Add(new AllowAnonymousInjectingConvention(controllerName, actionName));
            })
```

The custom convention, in this case `AllowAnonymousInjectingConvention`, imlements `IApplicationModelConvention`. The Apply() method checks on which controllers and actions it has to add the `AllowAnonymousFilter`:

```
        public AllowAnonymousInjectingConvention(string controllerName, string? actionName)
        {
            _controller = controllerName;
            _action = actionName;
        }

        public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
        {
            var filterModels = application.Controllers
                                         .Where(e => string.Equals(e.ControllerName, _controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                         .ToList<IFilterModel>();
            if (filterModels.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_action))
            {
                filterModels = filterModels.Cast<ControllerModel>()
                                           .SelectMany(e => e.Actions.Where(o => string.Equals(o.ActionName, _action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                                           .ToList<IFilterModel>();
            }
            foreach (var filterModel in filterModels)
            {
                filterModel.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
            }
        }
```

In the startup, I configured the following `DefaultPolicy` which only checks if the user is authenticated:

```
options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                   .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                   .Build();
```

The application is configured to require authorization:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers()
                .RequireAuthorization();
            });
```

The `DefaultPolicy` should not be used when the controller action has an `[AllowAnonymous]`-attribute. When adding an `[AllowAnonymous]`-attribute directly to the controller action, it does indeed work correctly. The `DefaultPolicy` is skipped and unauthenticated users can access the controller action.

However, this does not seem to work when an `AllowAnonymousFilter` is added instead of the `[AllowAnonymous]`-attribute.

When using filters, the `DefaultPolicy` is still checked. A call with an added `AllowAnonymousFilter` will still check the `DefaultPolicy` resulting in only allowing authenticated users instead of anonymous (unauthenticated) users.

Is there a way to ignore the `DefaultPolicy` for a controller action when an `AllowAnonymousFilter` has been added to that action? Or is there a better way of implementing this?

Comment: You can try to implement AllowAnonymousAttribute, like `public class allow : AllowAnonymousAttribute{}`.